# How to run scala test case using Maven

Tags: maven, scalatest

I have written my project in java and scala.
I have written one scala test case for unit testing scala code.
However, I am not sure about the path it has to be stored to because maven says,

> T E S T S
>
> ------------------------------------------------------- There are no tests to run.
>
> Results :
>
> Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

Can anybody help me with how can I have maven pick my scala test file stored under src/test/scala?

[image: code structure]
[image: pom-part1[![][1][1]][image: pom-part2[![][3]]][4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jw1vN.png)

Comment: How do you run your tests? In which folder are the tests stored?

Comment: @Marek- Right now i am trying to run it through maven and Jenkins. My Jenkins job calls maven to run these test cases but it never picks up any.

Answer (score 0):

Below should be the folder structure to run your test cases. Just like java test case execution from maven scala test will also execute....

[image]

please go through [scala with Maven](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/scala-with-maven.html) doc here

- Please refer sample [pom.xml here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/steveloughran/helf/master/pom.xml)
- http://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/using_the_scalatest_maven_plugin

***To use the ScalaTest Maven plugin, you need to disable SureFire and enable ScalaTest. Here's an example of how to do this in your pom.xml:***

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.7</version>
  <configuration>
    <skipTests>true</skipTests>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
<!-- enable scalatest -- >
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.scalatest</groupId>
  <artifactId>scalatest-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <configuration>
    <reportsDirectory>${project.build.directory}/surefire-reports</reportsDirectory>
    <junitxml>.</junitxml>
    <filereports>WDF TestSuite.txt</filereports>
  </configuration>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>test</id>
      <goals>
        <goal>test</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Hi Ram, I did try that structure but maven would never execute those test cases when called through jenkins. Moreover, it does not even pick those tests. I was wondering if the test cases should be relevant to the code? will it work with some sample test case which is not related to the code? Also will it work for the single test case?

Comment: oh i see. what about local execution of maven build through your command prompt(not with jenkins). in normal case, it should execute..

Comment: what is the command you are using to execute with jenkins make sure that `skipTests` is not present in that....

Comment: also see @Ignore for test cases were not configured. in that case need your sample test case to see and suggest you.... need more information.suggest you to respond quickly to close this

Comment: the command that I m using in Jenkins is below-                                       clean package install deploy -X -Dtest=sinplescala test -s /ds_build/GBM/Production/Dev_Support/util/FTP/settings.xml -Dmaven.test.failure.ignore=true -Drpf.release.version=1.0.10-releases                                                                                                       sinplescala is the name of my testcase file.

Comment: I am not sure if my pom.xml is correctly configured as the scalatest.I am using this link to configure it- http://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/using_the_scalatest_maven_plugin   but it doesn't help.

Comment: what should be the pom.xml for maven to pick scala test?

Comment: I have tried the pom.xml that you have mentioned but still Jenkins does not pick the test case. It says- [36mDiscovery completed in 309 milliseconds.[0m
[36mRun starting. Expected test count is: 0[0m
[32mDiscoverySuite:[0m
[36mRun completed in 356 milliseconds.[0m
[36mTotal number of tests run: 0[0m
[36mSuites: completed 1, aborted 0[0m
[36mTests: succeeded 0, failed 0, canceled 0, ignored 0, pending 0[0m     [DEBUG] -- end configuration --
[INFO] [surefire:test {execution: default-test}]
[INFO] No tests to run.

Comment: is there anyway I can share my pom.xml with you? and Also, is there anyway I can share the screenshot of my code structure?

Comment: you can add screen shot or pom structure by editing your original question.

Comment: I saw your screen shots but I can NOT  see you followed my instructions of disable sure fire plug in and  using ` <groupId>org.scalatest</groupId>
  <artifactId>scalatest-maven-plugin</artifactId>`

Comment: I did follow your instrctions- please see this:                                                    <plugin>
     <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
     <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
     <version>2.7</version>
     <configuration>
       <skipTests>true</skipTests>
     </configuration>
  </plugin>

Comment: <plugin>
  <groupId>org.scalatest</groupId>
  <artifactId>scalatest-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <configuration>
    <reportsDirectory>${project.build.directory}/surefire-reports</reportsDirectory>
    <junitxml>.</junitxml>
    <filereports>WDF TestSuite.txt</filereports>
  </configuration>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>test</id>
      <goals>
        <goal>test</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>

Comment: It skips all the tests and says- test cases are skipped.

Comment: I am getting this through Jenkins- [INFO] [scalatest:test {execution: test}]
[36mRun starting. Expected test count is: 0[0m
[32mDiscoverySuite:[0m
[36mRun completed in 379 milliseconds.[0m
[36mTotal number of tests run: 0[0m
[36mSuites: completed 1, aborted 0[0m
[36mTests: succeeded 0, failed 0, ignored 0, pending 0[0m
[32mAll tests passed.[0m

Comment: I have added this dependency-<dependency>
    <groupId>org.scalatest</groupId>
    <artifactId>scalatest_2.10</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.1</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

Comment: I am not sure if it is picking my scala test or not! I am expecting, it should say number of test cases run- 1 because I have one .scala file inside src/test/scala